# computing a difficult integral using software

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, math-software

I'd like to compute the following integral. I've tried SAGE but it just runs for 15 minutes then stops.. not sure what that means. If anyone wants to take a crack with mathematica or anything, please feel free

> qA = var('qA')
>
> qB = var('qB')
>
> qM = var('qM')
>
> rA = var('rA')
>
> rB = var('rB')
>
> rM = var('rM')
>
> c  = var('c')
>
> expression = exp(-(qA/qB*(c-rA)+rB))/(1+exp(-(qA/qB*(c-rA)+rB)))*exp(-(qA/qM*(c-rA)+rM))/(1+exp(-(qA/qM*(c-rA)+rM)))*(exp(-c))/(1+exp(-c))^2
>
> integral = integrate(expression,c,0,infinity)

here it is in latex:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\exp\left\{ -\left(\frac{q_{A}}{q_{B}}(c-r_{A})+r_{B}\right)\right\} }{1+\exp\left\{ -\left(\frac{q_{A}}{q_{B}}(c-r_{A})+r_{B}\right)\right\} }\right)\left(\frac{\exp\left\{ -\left(\frac{q_{A}}{q_{M}}(c-r_{A})+r_{M}\right)\right\} }{1+\exp\left\{ -\left(\frac{q_{A}}{q_{M}}(c-r_{A})+r_{M}\right)\right\} }\right)\frac{\exp\left\{ -c\right\} }{\left(1+\exp\left\{ -c\right\} \right)^{2}}dc
$$

I mean I guess first question..is it even doable?

Comment: Mathematica could not evaluate even a stripped-down version of this integral in closed form.

Comment: thanks for giving it a shot.

Comment: so I should have mentioned that you can assume all the parameters and c are all nonnegative (I think). Anyway, sage seemed to like that, but still couldn't solve it..

Comment: but yea I'm probably going to send this back unsolved